# Admob Displays Ads in Emulator but Not on Phone

Tags: java, android, admob

I am able to view test ads on the emulator but when I install the same app (release version) on a phone with regular / test ads, the banner doesn't show.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2011402599521768/7649302302"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_feedback"
    ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Ad loading code:

```
// Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-2011402599521768~7160726450");

AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

// Test ads:
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

//AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your real device might be not registered as a test device, try to read this document about test requests:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices
You can replace it with a regular request to know if adding a test device is the problem.

Comment: I tried a regular request (AdRequest.Builder().build()) with no success

Comment: Are you sure the device is connected to the Internet?

Comment: Yes it is connected

Comment: What about the parent of the AdView? Is it a RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout?

Comment: It is ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by logging into Admob and configuring payments, then some minutes later the ads began to be served.